# Weapon attachment kick effects

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Does anyone have stats on how much the silencer attachment reduces recoil compared to the kick proficiency and grip attachment? It seems to vary from weapon to weapon, but I'm not sure. Additionally, the ACOG scope attachment sometimes seems to increase kick - I know it pushes the range flip of weapons farther out, so it makes sense. Is this a documented phenomenon? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The silencer 'officially' does not reduce recoil, although on certain weapons it does. The ACR 6.8 with a silencer behaves completely differently than an ACR with no attachment, and in my opinion the ACR should always be run with a silencer. The ACOG does not increase kick, but when you're looking through it, it appears to because your field of view is smaller so a small rise appears larger. It is best to use burst or semi-auto weapons with the ACOG, or manually burst-fire the weapon.

Comment: Can you list which weapons experience recoil modification upon the addition of a silencer? For instance, the G36C has virtually no recoil with silence/kick but an enormous amount of recoil with silence/ACOG.

Comment: I don't know for sure. But I think the G36 with silencer/kick has more to do with the effect of the kick than the silencer. Some weapons benefit from kick more, some hardly at all. See this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnzRqQfciXg&list=PL70C70064F5915655&index=7&feature=plpp_video
user Tmartn on Youtube (author of that video) has a lot of good tip videos

Comment: There is absolutely no reduction in recoil on the ACR with a silencer. It's just the muzzle flash that is removed, and thus you can inherently adjust for the recoil better.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - It's possible that it has been patched, but the ACR definitely behaved differently with the silencer - more so than any other weapon. It also did not seem to decrease range as it was supposed to. Tmartn did a video on YouTube about it, but I can't seem to find the specific one